# Find files that are newer than another with similar name, but different extension

Tags: shell, find, file-comparison

This is fairly simple issue that has been bothering me. A little backstory. I have a folder full of scripts. These scripts takes data files `*.dat` and generates output in `*.eps`.  The extension of my scripts is `*.plt`. I create a one line shell script that runs all the `*.plt` files in that folder.

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -name "*.plt" -exec {} \;
```

I just want to make sure that all the `*.pdf` images I will use in my document are up to date. For a time, the one line script was good. But when the number of files is over 50, it takes some time to run. I rarely change the data files, but make changes to the `*.plt` scripts frequently. The scripts are written in such way that a script named `this_script_does_something.plt` will create a file called `this_script_does_something.eps`.

Hence, here's my question.

- Is there way to write a refined shell script that executes only the `*.plt` files that are newer than the similarly called `*.eps`?

I know I can do this in Python. But it seems like cheating. I also know that I can look for the newer `*.eps` and execute all the `*.plt` that are newer than this. This will solve my problem, for most practical cases. I just realized about this option while I was typing the question, so thank you SX. However, as a didactic exercise, and to solve my original doubt, I would like to search for individual cases: compare the modification time of each `*.plt` with each `*.eps`, and execute the script only when they are more recent than the output. Is it possible? Can it be done in a single line?

EDIT: I forgot to add, that the `*.plt` scripts should also execute when there are no homonym `*.eps` files, which normally means that the script is new and has not been executed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd be using:

```
#!/bin/bash

for plt in *.plt
do
    eps=$(basename "$plt" .plt).eps
    if [ "$plt" -nt "$eps" ]
    then "$plt"
    fi
done
```

This uses the Bash/Korn shell operator `-nt` for 'newer than' (and there's the converse `-ot` operator for 'older than').  I'm assuming the files are all in a single directory so there's no need for a recursive search.  If that's not correct, then use a separate:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c "cd {}; new-script.sh" \;
```

(where `new-script.sh` is the script I just showed).  Or use the Bash extension `**` operator:

```
for plt in *.plt **/*.plt
```

You might need to set the Bash `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This generates nothing when an expansion does not match any files.

---

Also generate when the `.eps` file does not exist:

```
#!/bin/bash

for plt in *.plt
do
    eps=$(basename "$plt" .plt).eps
    if [ ! -f "$eps" ] || [ "$plt" -nt "$eps" ]
    then "$plt"
    fi
done
```

The only not-completely-generic shell feature in this is the `-nt` operator.  If your `/bin/sh` doesn't support it, check the `/bin/[` command — it might — or use Korn Shell or Bash instead of `/bin/sh` in the shebang line.

Comment: The first script does exactly what I wanted (yes, all the `*.plt` are in the same folder). I would only add an extra condition to the if test, to execute if `$eps` does not exist.
I was trying complex one liners, but this approach is simpler

Comment: I recommend testing for the non-existent file before trying to compare the time of the existing file with the non-existent one.  Otherwise, that works fine.  The `-s` checks for a non-empty (but existing) file; `-f` doesn't mind if the file is empty.

Comment: Something like
`if [ ! -f "$eps" ] || [ "$plt" -nt "$eps" ]`
I deleted my previous comment, as I couldn't edit it.
Thanks

Comment: I meant: `if [ ! -s "$eps" ] || [ "$plt" -nt "$eps" ]`.  The commands are evaluated left-to-right and short-circuited, so if the `$eps` file doesn't exist, the condition will be true; if it does exist but is older than (or the same age as) the `$plt` file, then the condition will be true.  The chances are reasonable that the `-nt` test for a non-existent file behaves sanely.  (I just tested `if [ bombard.c -nt bombard.non-existent ]; then echo "OK"; else echo 'Oops!'; fi` in a directory with a file `bombard.c` present, and it printed `OK`. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ I tried with a file called `oldest` stamped 1969-12-31 16:01:00 and 1904-12-31 16:01:00 (in timezone UTC-08:00 — aka US/Pacific) and the comparison `if [ bombard.non-existent -nt oldest ]; then echo "OK"; else echo 'Oops!'; fi` printed 'Oops!'.  So a non-existent file compares older than any file; you may not need the extra test.  You should double check this, of course. I tested on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with Bash (3.2.53…).

Answer (score 1):

This script should do what you expect:

```
find . -name "*.eps" -exec sh -c \
     'plt=$(basename "$1" eps)plt; [ "$plt" -nt "$1" ] && $plt' sh {} \;
```

It will recurse into subdirectories, if any. If you don't want that, and you use GNU find, a simple workaround is to run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.eps" -exec sh -c \
     'plt=$(basename "$1" eps)plt; [ "$plt" -nt "$1" ] && $plt' sh {} \;
```

If you don't use GNU find, you might use that syntax instead:

```
find *.eps -type f -exec sh -c \
     'plt=$(basename "$1" eps)plt; [ "$plt" -nt "$1" ] && $plt' sh {} \;
```

but the latter might fail with an "arg list too long" error if you have a very large number of files matching the `*.eps` pattern. Any solution based on a `for file in *.extension` loop would suffer from the same issue.

Note also that `-nt` is not specified by POSIX so depending on your system, you might want to specifically state the shell to use instead of `sh` (mainstream shells like `dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, `ksh93` or `zsh` do support `-nt`). For example on Solaris 10, you would use:

```
find . -name "*.eps" -exec ksh -c \
     'plt=$(basename "$1" eps)plt; [ "$plt" -nt "$1" ] && $plt' ksh {} \;
```

Edit:

As the script should run if the `.eps` file does not exist, the command should loop on the `.plt` files instead, eg:

```
find *.plt -type f -exec bash -c \
     'eps=$(basename "$0" plt)eps;
     [ ! -f "$eps" -o "$0" -nt "$eps" ] && "$0"' "{}" \;
```

Comment: Cool. It's close. I forgot to mention in my question that the script should also run when the `*.eps` file does not exits (a newly created script)
For some reason, I'm having issues with the last part: `sh {}`. My scripts are `gnuplot`, and the first line (the interpreter) is `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot`. Should I still add the sh?

Comment: I have removed the `sh` although it shouldn't really hurt. May be is it the `{}` that choke with `gnuplot`, I quoted it just in case.

Comment: Still having issues with it. Maybe I was to eager to ask for a single line command. Probably is something on my bashrc that's killing it. My list of alias is inherited from someone that also got it from someone else. I really gotta clean that up. Thanks. I'll accept the other answer

Comment: There was a mistake in my last script, I used an variable that no longer existed. This should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @jlliagre. I already modified my script bases on the structure of the other answer. I will test yours soon. Thanks again